# Dynamic SQL - Query different database depending on parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a situation where I need to get data from one of over 100 database (all with the exact same schema) depending on a parameter passed to a stored procedure.

The way I've been trying to do this is to build a dynamic SQL statement to execute with `sp_executesql`:

(This is just a test script BTW):

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
set @sql = 'select top 10 * from [SERVER].@dbName.dbo.[LL]'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@dbName nvarchar(50)', @dbName = N'[TheDatabase1]'
```

This gives the error `Incorrect syntax near '@dbName'.`

Is there any other option I might consider?

PS - the database schema is not within my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot parameterize the database name - you will need to concatenate it directly.

```
set @sql = 'select top 10 * from [SERVER].' + N'[TheDatabase1]' + '.dbo.[LL]'
```

[Here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) is very good (though lengthy) article about dynamic SQL, by Erland Sommarskog.

Comment: I thought that might be the case - I was just concerned that the query plans would be duplicated. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @David - Seeing as these are different databases, I would expect different query plans regardless. Apart from dynamically constructing them by concatenation, I don't believe there is any work around. Read the article - it might give you some ideas.